# Delphi and __uuidof

Tags: windows, delphi, com, guid

I'm porting a `C` source code to Delphi and came to: `memcpy(&FFileOperation,&__uuidof(IFileOperation), sizeof(GUID));`.

What I have so far:

`FFileOperation` is a `TGUID` type.

`CopyMemory (@FFileOperation, @iFileOperation, SizeOf (TGUID));`

But I don't know how to use it properly.
What would be the alternative or similar command in Delphi? And what does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use that when you needed to obtain the GUID of an interface. In your case you are looking for the GUID of `IFileOperation`.

In Delphi the compiler performs magic for you. Where you would need to use `__uuidof` in C++ you can simply pass the interface type itself, `IFileOperation` in this case. You can use an interface type in any context that expects a `GUID` and so long as that interface has a GUID defined, the compiler will do the rest for you.

So, in C++ you might write:

```
QueryInterface(__uuidof(IFileOperation), ...)
```

In Delphi you would write:

```
QueryInterface(IFileOperation, ...)
```

Just to show you how pervasive this magic is, I offer the following fun program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  GUID: TGUID;

begin
  GUID := IInterface;
  Writeln(GUIDToString(GUID));
  Readln;
end.
```

which produces this output:

```
{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
```

---

Looking at your update, you do not need to use `CopyMemory`. You can write that line of code like this:

```
FFileOperation := IFileOperation;
```

However, the variable naming is odd. The variable named `FFileOperation` really should be declared like this:

```
FIFileOperationGUID: TGUID;
```

---

But I doubt that you even need the variable at all. It looks like it only ever holds that GUID. That GUID is known at compile time. If you hold it anywhere, hold it in a constant. But do you need to hold it anywhere? Surely you can remove it and replace all uses with `IFileOperation`.

Comment: Would you be so kind and add where `QueryInterface` is located at? I'm using XE4

Comment: [`QueryInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682521.aspx) is one of the three methods defined by `IInterface`, aka [`IUnknown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509.aspx). In any case, it doesn't matter where you use it, the principle is the same. Simply remove the `__uuidof()` and let the Delphi compiler do the rest.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my question. It needs a variable when I try to copy the memory.

Comment: The answer is just the same. If you need a variable put it in a variable. Look at the program in my answer. It does just that. But in your case you don't need to replicate `memcpy`. You can do plain assignment.

Comment: OK. But take a read of my latest update. I strongly suspect that you don't need that variable at all. I suspect that the code you are porting can be greatly simplified in Delphi.